# How to show the chart dynamically in phonegap application back end sqlite?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm doing an app using Phonegap (Cordova) and I'm using jquery mobile for that. I want to know how show the chart dynamically. The data of chart will retrieve from sqlite database. The chart will be in pie chart. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() { 
     var sqlitedata ;
     //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
         //     [ 
          //    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          //    ['Work',     11],
          //    ['Eat',      2],
          //    ['Commute',  2],
          //    ['Watch TV', 2],
          //    ['Sleep',    7] 
          //  ]
         //   );
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(sqlitedata );

            var options = {
              title: 'My Daily Activities'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
```

// Wait for device API libraries to load

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Populate the database
//
function populateDB(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');//comments this line after first user
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');//comments this line after first user
}

// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback

  function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
     var row;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " +    results.rows.item(i).data);
```

// get your two columns here and insert it on

```
    sqlitedata="[[" +  row[0].item(i) + "], [" +  row[1].item(i) + "]]"
    }
} 

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}


        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

for fetching data please read [phonegap document](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Comment: but i want retrieve the data from sqlite dynamically?

Comment: can you  fetch data in query from sqlite on page load? ie two columns you need in pie chart

Comment: Yeah..Using phonegap i can fetch the data from sqlite

Comment: can you make a variable and add your data like this in it [
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]
you can do this when fetching data in loop

Comment: i tried that but its not giving result. Can you give me the code to fetch the data from sqlite

Comment: you mean you cant fetch data from sqlite? can you show your code where you get data from sqlite

Comment: function getfromtable()
{
   db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB)
}


function queryDB(tx) 
{
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [],errorCB);
 }

Comment: post your code in question and 1) have you checked that your table has values 2) what editor you are using?xcode or eclipse

Comment: you are missing this line var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);

Comment: i am using Telerik app buider